# How to set both condition to apply skeleton loader and as well as empty page for my orders page in vueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web, vuejs2

I have applied the skeleton loader till the data loads. But i want to show an empty order page if there is no data or no order coming. I want to know the condition for both situation to show both loader and empty basket page. I am stuck how to do this. I am newbie to vuetify. The following is my code:

````
<template>
  <v-container>
    <div class="text-h2" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
      Order History
    </div>
<div v-if="orders.length < 1">
  <v-skeleton-loader
      v-for="n in 5"
      :key="n"
      class="flex-row"
      elevation="2"
      max-width="100%"
      style="margin-bottom: 20px"
      transition="scale-transition"
      type="list-item-avatar-three-line"
  >
  </v-skeleton-loader>
</div>
    <v-card
        v-else
      v-for="order in orders"
      :key="order.id"
      class="mx-auto google-font mb-6"
      max-width="auto">
      <v-list-item-content>
        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="10">
            <v-list-item-title class="mb-2 ml-4" style="font-size: 100%; margin-right: 5px"
              >OrderID: {{ order.id }}</v-list-item-title
            >
            <v-list-item-subtitle
              style="color: grey; font-size: 100%;"
              class="ml-4"
              >Items {{ order.ITEMS.length }}</v-list-item-subtitle
            >
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="2">
            <v-list-item-title
              class="float-right mb-2 mr-6"
              style="font-size: 100%;"
              >₹{{ order.TOTAL_COST }}</v-list-item-title
            >
            <v-list-item-subtitle
              style="color: grey; font-size: 85%;"
              class="mr-6 float-right"
              >{{ parseDate(order.ORDER_DATE) }}</v-list-item-subtitle
            >
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
        <v-divider></v-divider>
      </v-list-item-content>
      <v-btn
        text
        small
        style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 5px;"
        v-on:click="switchExpand(order.id)"
        :color="getStoreColor"
      >
        Details<v-icon>{{
          expandedItems.indexOf(order.id) > -1
            ? "mdi-chevron-up"
            : "mdi-chevron-down"
        }}</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-card>
    <v-btn
        outlined
        rounded
        :color="getStoreColor"
        @click="logout">
      Logout
    </v-btn>
  </v-container>
</template> ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you said, you need two conditions.
for your skeleton loader, I noticed the condition you made is:

```
v-if="orders.length < 1"
```

which is not correct for loading state, the correct solution for a loading state is creating a separated reactive property to detect loading state, let's say we have

```
data() {
  return {
      loading: true // data is loading by default, assuming you are fetching data on created or mounted hooks
   }
}
```

and when you do your API call, you should do:

```
methods: {
  async fetchData() {
    this.loading = true // start loading, show the skeleton loader, I know it's ture already, but let's say you will call this more than one time
    const apiRes = await this.myAPICall()
    this.loading = false// loading finished, hide the skeleton loader
  }
}
```

this way, even if the response is empty, the loader will be hided, because loading property only detect the loading state of your API call

your condition to check whether the length is bigger than 1 or not, it's not right because when the api response returns no orders, it will be equal to zero

and now, let's to move to our second and final condition, detecting whether there is orders or not, consider the following code:

```
computed: {
  isItEmptyState() {
    return this.orders.length < 1 && !this.loading
  }
}
```

the explanation of the code above, if there are no orders `this.orders.length < 1` and the data is loaded `!this.loading` loading is false, so we are done loading the data

and then simply you can do:

```
<div v-if="isItEmptyState">whatever placeholder you want</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It Works.Actually your logic is right.

Comment: You are welcome! glad to hear that, don't forget to accept the answer